# ionic - this.navctrl.push() NotWorking

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I make API Call and when response success navigate to another page as you will see.
the Call return response but don't push to another page.

My Function :

```
signup() {
  this.showLoader();
  this.authService.postData(this.userData, 'Regestier').then((result) => {
      this.responseData = result;
      console.log(this.responseData);

      localStorage.setItem('userData', this.responseData);
      this.navCtrl.push(DashboardPage);
      this.loading.dismiss();

    },

    (err) => {
      // Error log
      this.loading.dismiss();

    });

}
```

Comment: You might want to `JSON.stringify()` before setting an item . `localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));`

Comment: My Problem "  this.navCtrl.push(DashboardPage);  " does not working

Comment: Yeah I mean. Just saw an issue to highlight it. Has nothing to do with your problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with **`setRoot`**. That way the new component is the root, which in your case would be the DashboardPage.

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage, {}, {animate: true, direction: 'forward'});
```